# What are the benefits of using CloudAdapter over the deprecated BotFrameworkAdapter?

Tags: botframework

[BotFrameworkAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder/botframeworkadapter?view=botbuilder-ts-latest) has been deprecated and [CloudAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.integration.aspnet.core.cloudadapter?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) is the replacement so we must port our bots.

Have searched all the Microsoft and BotBuilder sites and can not locate any documentation describing the benefits of the new adapter and any porting guidelines.  (Yes, there is sample [echobot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/02.echo-bot/AdapterWithErrorHandler.cs) code but no background or context for the change)

For example, for a self-hosted C#/.NET Teams Bot built using the Botbuilder using Azure AD for Authentication, what new functionality is gained when we port to the new adapter?

Are there any performance gains?

For those who have successfully ported their Teams bots to the CloudAdapter, any gotchas or learning that would benefit others starting this task?

Comment: Landed here looking for docs con `CloudAdapter` but none exists.. Also this new class implements deprecated interfaces so...